# Migrating DocuSign from Development to Production changes UI completely

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to figure out why on earth our UI has completely changed after migrating from development to production. Here is what the UI looked like in development:

[image]

And here is what it looks like after changing our API calls AND migrating our branding from development:

[image]

Notice the entirely different header and now there is a sidebar to the right? What gives? I see no mention of this in any documentation for migrating from development to production.

Comment: Can you please provide steps to move DocuSign from Demo to Production? I integrated it on my site and now I need to deploy it in Production. DocuSign says you need 20+ test transaction. What does it mean environment='test' or environment='demo'? I'm following this [document](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/API%20Certification%20Guide.pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable this setting on your production account:

**Preferences** > **Features** > **Use DocuSign Winter ’15 Signing Experience Now**

The difference you are seeing is the Classic Signing Experience and the Winter '15 Signing Experience.

Comment: Yes and just to add, DocuSign made a major update to its UI earlier this year so there's an older UI (called Classic DocuSign Experience) and there's a newer UI simply called New DocuSign Experience (NDSE).  You can switch back and forth between old and new using a toggle button in your account preferences.